# Luaunit - how to test functions that return multiple values

Tags: unit-testing, lua

I have the following lua code:

```
 test_me=function()
      if mood == "happy" then
          return true, atable
      else
          return false, "go away"
      end
 end
```

Luaunit test file called test_mood.lua:

```
test_mymood=function()
   luaunit.assertEquals(mymod.test_me,true)
end
```

When I run this unit test, it fails like so:

```
1..1
# Started on Wed May 16 20:14:05 2018
not ok 1        test_mymood
    test_mood.lua:72: expected: true, actual: function: 0x97c699b3e20
# Ran 1 tests in 0.004 seconds, 0 successes, 1 failure
```

It is passing, but it's getting the table back i think.
If you can point me in the right direction, that'd be great.  Reading their docs right now but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
luaunit.assertEquals(mymod.test_me(),true)
```

*with parentheses* so that the function result is returned instead of the function itself?

You can see it wrong whan the message from the test says the actual value is a *function*:

```
test_mood.lua:72: expected: true, actual: function: 0x97c699b3e20
------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table.pack()` to grab all return results, include the `nil`.

```
local r = table.pack(your_function())
for i = 1, r.n do
    print(i, r[i]) -- one of return result maybe nil
end
```